# Display HTML without stripping tags or converting to html entities

Tags: php, html, summernote

I want to display HTML as it is created in summernote editor in a page. But when I use echo it displays HTML as `"<div><h1>"` etc. It did not display the contents as in the editor.

I want is there any function to display HTML as it is created inside a WYSIWYG editor in PHP.

This is the code I have

```
<div class="post_content">
    <div class="post_meta">
        <h2>
            <?php echo ucfirst($questionpaper[0]['title']); ?>
        </h2>
    </div>

    <?php
    $description = $questionpaper[0]['description'];
    echo $description;
    ?>
</div>
```

I want to display the description as it is created inside summernote editor. But currently I am getting output with HTML tags as plain text.

Currently the output I am getting looks like this:

```
<div>Lorem ipsum.</div><div><br></div><div>Lorem ipsum</div>
```

But I want the HTML tags parsed. Is there any function or library in PHP for doing this.

Comment: Can you please explain clearly or show your code

Comment: _“But currently I am getting output with HTML tags as plain text”_ - 
_You_ are making this display as code, by using `htmlentities` on the value ...

Comment: I edited the code, I want to display html not as plain text but as we see in summer note editor

Comment: @user2634873 See my updated answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are converting the tags to plain text using `htmlentities()` here:

```
echo htmlentities($description);
```

Change it to just:

```
echo $description;
```

#### EDIT

You just updated your question removing the `htmlentities()` I was referring to, but if you are still getting plain text you can try to do this:

```
echo html_entity_decode($description);
```

Comment: @user2634873 Great! Glad I could help! Remember to mark correct answers as such and upvote all helpful answers or comments.